# change value of dropdownlist based of another dropdwonlis using ajax jquery on Core MVC ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlCentre", ViewBag.Centre_Commercial as List<SelectListItem>,
                       " -- Sélectionnez Centre Commercial --", new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlLocal", new List<SelectListItem>(),
                       " -- Sélectionnez Local --", new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>
```

I have list of Center and list of local :what i want is when i select Any dropdownlist of center other than local DropDownListFor local has to change.
Controller Action :

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetLocalsList(int id)
        {
            List<Local> lstLocal= new List<Local>();
            lstLocal = objLocal.GetLocalsData(id).ToList();
            return Json(lstLocal);

        }
```

and view :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlCentre", ViewBag.Centre_Commercial as List<SelectListItem>,
                       " -- Sélectionnez Centre Commercial --", new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlLocal", new List<SelectListItem>(),
                       " -- Sélectionnez Local --", new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetLocalsList")",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                        $("#ddlLocal").append("<option value='" + row.id + "'>" + row.id + "</option>")
                    });
                   },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to  change value of dropdownlist based of another dropdwonlis,you use the method $(“”).change,and if you want to pass the data by ajax to controller,you can do liking the following code：

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlCentre", ViewBag.Centre_Commercial as List<SelectListItem>,
                       " -- Sélectionnez Centre Commercial --", new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlLocal", new List<SelectListItem>(),
                       " -- Sélectionnez Local --", new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#ddlCentre").change(function () {
            $("#ddlLocal").empty().append('<option>-- Sélectionnez Local --</option>');
            var id = $(this).val();
            if (id != "") {
                $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetLocalsList")",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                data: { 'id': id },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                        $("#ddlLocal").append("<option value='" + row.id + "'>" + row.name + "</option>")
                    });
                   },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
            }

        })
    </script>
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public static List<Local> Locals = new List<Local> { new Local { Id = "1", Name = "Local1", CenterId = "1" }, new Local { Id = "2", Name = "Local2", CenterId = "2" } };
    public static List<Center> Centers = new List<Center> { new Center { Id = "1", Name = "Center1" }, new Center { Id = "2", Name = "Center2" } };
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetLocalsList(int id)
    {

        List<Local> lstLocal = new List<Local>();
        lstLocal = Locals.Where(l =>l.CenterId==id.ToString()).ToList();
        return Json(lstLocal);

    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetLocalsList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lstLocal = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Center center in Centers) {
            lstLocal.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = center.Id, Text = center.Name });
        }
        ViewBag.ddlCentre = lstLocal;

        return View();

    }
```

[image]

Comment: not worked for me because i work with asp.net core mvc view razor in above my code thanks in advance

Comment: I also used view page in mvc.I updated my answer to add the code of my controller.I didn't  use a database.But I used the static list to get and select data from it and the code worked.So I think you can debug if the controller can get the correct data from database.Finally,I hope you can share the error of your code.